# Find $\alpha,\beta,\gamma\in S_4$ such that $\alpha\beta=\beta\alpha$, $\beta\gamma=\gamma\beta$ but $\alpha\gamma\neq\gamma\alpha$.

Tags: permutations

Can you give an example for $\alpha,\beta,\gamma\in S_4$ (permutation group for the set $\{1,2,3,4\}$) such that $\alpha\beta=\beta\alpha$, $\beta\gamma=\gamma\beta$ but $\alpha\gamma\neq\gamma\alpha$. I have tried many times but failed.

Comment: What have you tried? What is $S_4$ group, there is no standard notation for stuff like this and you can't assume everyone uses the same convention.

Comment: @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost: to be fair, $S_4$ *is* standard notation (at least in this context).

Comment: Start by letting $\beta$ be the identity element.

Comment: @hello Perhaps it is. Perhaps it's not. That's besides the point. The comment was a general hint at how Math SE questions should be formatted: Work needs to be shown, and it's better to provide all the  relevant details.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$\alpha=(12),\beta =(34)(12),\gamma=(13)(24).$

$\alpha \beta \alpha =\beta .$

$\beta\gamma \beta=\gamma .$

$\alpha \gamma \alpha =(23)(14).$

Comment: Please don't encourage low quality questions.